# how to create capabilities in texonomy for new role

Tags: php, wordpress

Dear WordPress developer,
I want to create add new role, where have only custom post and taxonomy category when login those type author.
I have all ready create role and custom post type and taxonomy, and when login those role user in dashboard then show profile menu,custom post type with taxonomy and extra show menu post category and tag that i want to remove.

Please help me which those role capabilities add_cap in add_role() and register_taxonomy() function.My code bellow
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this plugin to create custom roles and select capitalists for them 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

then use this plugin to edit what post-type and stuf a visible for them
https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/

its easier this way

Comment: I want to without plugin.!!!!

Comment: why without plugin its so much work ... trust me ...

Comment: Ok Thanks you sir.After that i have recent face problem.Main site archive.php page does not work.But network site archive.php work.Please sir help me.